# Smooth slideup/down after creating DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a larga amount of xml data in $(db). When a certain element is clicked, a function traverses through $(db) and creates new DOM elements inside a hidden div. How can I then smoothly slide down the div?

```
$('li').live('click', function(){
    // many $('div.content').append(....
    $('div.content').slideDown();
});
```

In the above example the div.content becomes visible, however without the slide effect. If I, instead of creating DOM elements load an html document with the vary same content, the slide effect works properly. I think that when creating a lot of new DOM elements the browser jams, and then cannot perform a smooth animation. How could I sort this problem out? Would it be possible to create all the DOM elements inside a variable, and then display it as it would happen when you use .load()?

Comment: Have you tired to move the slideDown call to the end of your append loop, so it executes sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

If you can select the newly created element from the DOM, this method will work nicely (needs jQuery). You will simply show the elements you created and then scroll the browser into view.

```
function scrollTo(element){
    $("html, body").animate({
         scrollTop: $(element).position().top
    });
}
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work either. The animation doesn't work. It works if I load all data via ajax, but doesn't work after creating a few hundreds of new DOM elements. The same problem - the browser seems to jam a bit.